# git ignore files that are causing merge conflict

Tags: git

I have a lot of bin and obj files that I added to the repository when I first created it. I checked out from master an made changes to the branch. When I try to merge it back I get

```
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
 (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

    modified:   (code I want merged from branch)
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)

    both modified:   (bin files I don't care about)
```

I realized I should've ignored the files earlier but I created a .gitignore file on my master and `git rm --cached` these files. They should no longer be tracked on the master. Yet when I try to merge I still get errors. Should I also make a .gitignore file on the branch and do the same thing? I would like to merge the first few files and just discard the changes to the both modified ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove those files from version control; it's not recommended to version binary files (unless third party code).

Then, create a .gitignore file in the workspace root with the following content:

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates

# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
#[Rr]elease/
#[Rr]eleases/
x64/
x86/
bld/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

and add it to Git. I deliberately included more rules that the ones you strictly need in order to give you some insight of how to add more ignore rules according to extension files and specific paths.

Your problem will dissapear from that moment on :)

Comment: I did this in my master but do I need to do it again in my branches since they were checked out before I created the .gitignore file?

Comment: No, you'd better merge all your branches from master so that all of them include this change (via merge traceability). If you apply the same change manually in the different branches you have, you'll get merge conflicts when merging those branches with each other, which is not the point.

Comment: what is merge traceability?

Comment: By merge traceability I mean the mechanism source control tools have in order to remember that a merge was done and not ask for it again and again. It's quite a complex and powerful concept.